# A C program cannot generate output into a log file after it reaches to a certain size

Tags: c, linux, printf, stdout, flush

In a multi-threading C program, I am trying to generate a log file for consistency checking. But after the log file reaches 142 G, it won't grow bigger anymore, while the program still running. Through `htop`, I see all memory occupied by the *yellow vertical line* even after exiting the program. But after I delete the log file, the memroy becomes empty.

In the program, I redirect `stdout` to a file.

```
    int fd = open("/mnt/driver_d/hewen/log.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("open file error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    dup2(fd, 1);
```

Then I use `printf` as usual to print information, and `fflush` after each `printf`.
Why it failed to print to the log file?

Comment: The user on whose behalf the program is run is probably limited in the size of file.  Look at `ulimit -f` for the file size limit.  You should consider a log rotation scheme so that your log file does not grow so large.

Comment: Maybe it is not your program but the terminal where you execute it occupies all the memory? Instead of duplicating stdout, try redirecting it to a file: `./myprogram > /mnt/driver_d/hewen/log.txt`

Comment: The output of `ulimit -f` is `unlimited`. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: You could modify the code to poke around with POSIX [`getrlimit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html) to find out what the file size limits are when the program is run, perhaps writing the information to the log file at startup (it doesn't normally change while the program is running unless it invokes `setrlimit()`).  Otherwise, there's no obvious reason for what you're observing.